# C# attributes executing code on function call

Tags: c#, attributes, custom-attributes

I'm writing a networked Client-Server application which - due to used framework (Unity3d) - mixes client and server code in a single file, which leads to confusing errors when function is called on a wrong side of application. I came up with an idea of writing custom attibutes - lets call them [Client] and [Server] - to decorate these functions, so they would log a warning if a function is called on a wrong side. Such attributes would also improve readability of code.

```
public class ClientAttribute : System.Attribute{
    public ClientAttribute(){
        if(Network.isServer) Debug.LogWarning("Function called on a wrong side!");
    }       
}

public class SomeClass{

    //this function will log warning if called on Server side
    [Client]
    SomeClientSideFunction(){}

}
```

Sadly, MSDN says that attributes constructor is called only after GetCustomAttributes() is called. Is there any way to tackle this problem using attributes or any other approach? Apart from manually writing

```
if(Network.isServer) Debug.LogWarning("Function called on a wrong side!");
```

at the beginning of every Client side function - as this will work, but won't improve readability.

Comment: Look into [PostSharp](http://www.postsharp.net/), there's nothing built into .NET.

Comment: I guess there is a way, Look into "Code access security" there are some attributes which which will be called before executing a method. But if you use it for any purpose other than security you're abusing it.

Comment: Look at this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.permissions.codeaccesssecurityattribute(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @Lasse Yeah, looks good, but it's a commercial use, so free version is out of question, while feature is so small that I don't really see product owner purchasing license for 300$. Thank you anyway!